# Complex User Permissions in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, authentication, permissions

I'm trying to hide and show sections of my angular app (I'll worry about protecting routes later)

The issue I'm having is, the backend is returning CRUD permissions for specific aspects of the database. Based on those permissions I'm supposed to decide how to hide and show elements of the UI. However there is never any direct one to one mapping.

So I need to decide how and show parts of the UI based on various combinations of permissions. For example "Show the reporting tab if they can "read" insertionOrder OR "read" finance" OR "read" OR "create" auction.

However this is a very small example usually the permissions are much longer and this was for only one section of the app.

I know I'm going to call a function inside ng-show I just don't know how to organize the function to account for all these use cases.

Any ideas is much appreciated.

Here's an example of the permissions array being returned:

```
{
"account": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"an_advertiser": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"an_insertion_order": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"auction": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"dashboard": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"finance": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"input_output": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"insertion_order": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"publisher": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"report": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
],
"user": [
    "read",
    "create",
    "update",
    "delete"
]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to be used internally if a trusted environment, but this sounds like it may be a security hole if you are trusting the client-side code to enforce your security policy. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but you can definitely not trust what comes back from the client even if you withhold crud actions. Anyone using something like Fiddler can modify the code send from the server, modify it, and run it again.

Comment: Yes it is an internal tool, and we're not using anything from the client for authorization. This is simply just hiding and showing elements of the UI based on user permissions returned FROM the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a suggestion, if you choose to change the permissions of your system.

I think you must add some hierarchy to the permissions.

I usually go with modules/actions.
So a module can have many actions.
Also instead of having read, create, update, delete i have (0: Blocked, 1: See, 2: Can).

Example:

```
{
    user: {
         module: 2,
         create: 2,
         edit: 2,
         name: 2,
         phone: 1,
         delete: 2
    },
    report: {
         module: 1,
         create: 2,
         edit: 0,
         reportA: 1,
         reportB: 2,
         delete: 2
    }
}
```

This way i can have full control of all actions. A module can be some part of the app with many actions. or you can go with a big module with all the components and then sub modules.

Since i use integers to the permissions i can just validate with a simple `<>=` sign.

I usually define a generic action like `module` to define if the person have access to the whole module.

```
function permTo(module, action){
  var mod = list[module];
  // not validating if module exists.
  var max = mod.module;
  return Math.min(mod[action], max);
}
```

Now with this `permTo('users', 'phone')` would give 1.

Now with this `permTo('users', 'name')` would give 2.

Now with this `permTo('report', 'create')` would give 1, because module is 1.